# How to create 3 instances of a class object and add them together via operator overloading?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add three Dim class objects together. I only know how to 1 Dim object with another, but given more than that I'm not quite sure. This is what I mean.

Dim(1.,1,1,1) + Dim(1.,1,1,1) + Dim(1.,1,1,1)-->3.0(1,1,1)

```
def __add__(self,right):
    self.each_value = 0        
    if type(right) not in [int,float,Dimensional]:
        raise TypeError
    elif type(right) is Dimensional:
        if self.__len__() != right.__len__():
            raise DimensionError
        print("inside elif")
        return Dimensional(self.value + right.value,self.length,self.mass,self.time)

    elif (type(right) in [int,float] and type(self) is Dimensional):
        if (self.length > 0 or self.mass > 0 or self.time > 0):
            raise DimensionError
        else:
            return Dimensional(self.value + right,self.length,self.mass,self.time)
    elif type(self) in [int,float] and type(right) is Dimensional:
        raise DimensionError


    return Dimensional(self.each_value,self.length,self.mass,self.time)

def __radd__(self,left):
    return self + left
```

Comment: Have you actually tried that? What error do you get? If you can add 2, I don't see why you can't add 3, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: I don't really know what to try. I mean does operator overloading add multiple objects together automatically?

Comment: @AivanEugeneGanChuaFrancisc -- Yes, `__add__` defines the operation of an item added to the item on it's right:  `a + b`.  To get `a + b + c`, python does `(a + b) + c` and so on and so forth.

Comment: Adding on to what @mgilson said, `(a + b)` becomes a new instance `d`. So `(a + b) + c` becomes `d + c`. Adding three instances becomes adding two instances, and you know how that works.

Comment: I know currently that the __add__ overload works for 2, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work for 3.  Unless maybe I shouldn't have returned Dimensional(...) and created a new variable that aggregates everything.

Comment: Aivan, have a look at the answer I put in.  if you agree. please select it as answer and upvote.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat it the way the language would for a simple add.  it will add the first two items together and come up with an intermediate result then it will add the intermediate result to the remaining item you were adding.   This will result in the add being called twice.  once to add the first two items and the 2nd time to add the result of the first call to the 3rd item.

To be more clear. Add is an operator that takes TWO operands and adds them.  overloading it will only allow the addition of an item to the item item its being added to.